# Mouse on Ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4 isn't working

Tags: mouse, raspberrypi

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4. I am completely out of the Raspberry environment. Keyboard works fine but the mouse doesn't.

What can be the problem here? How can I use the mouse?

Comment: What Ubuntu did you install?  Ubuntu Server by default provides a text interface (ie. no GUI or desktop is used). Yes you can add a desktop, but servers are more efficient if they aren't wasting resources (memory, processor power) making a pretty GUI/desktop work, so it's not included by default.  *I realize your release is 20.04 or the 2020-April release (yy.mm format is used), but there is Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu desktop, Ubuntu Core and numerous flavors*

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the Canonical tutorial on how to install Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi?

[Look here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi)

It basically comes down to this:

- First you flash Ubuntu server to an SD Card using the Pi Imager tool
- Then you configure network if necessary
- You boot up, and install a desktop if you want to (you have several options to choose from)

As long as you haven't installed a desktop, you only have the terminal display and no GUI, hence no use for a mouse.

Comment: Did you solve this? How?